# Smaato on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, smaato

I use Smaato ads for my app on Windows phone 8.1.
I was sign up Publisher on Smaato.com.
I was create new app and get Publisher Id and App Space Id.
i was add SOMAWP81 on References.
i use Smaato ads like this:
in xaml

```
<Grid>
      <soma:SomaAdViewer Name="somaAdViewer"
                         Width="320"
                         Height="50"/>
</Grid>
```

in code

```
        int AdSpaceId;
        int PublisherId;
        try
        {
            AdSpaceId = int.Parse(ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MySpaceId"].ToString());
            PublisherId = int.Parse(ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MyPubId"].ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            AdSpaceId = 0;
            PublisherId = 0;
        }

        somaAdViewer.Adspace = AdSpaceId;
        somaAdViewer.Pub = PublisherId;
        somaAdViewer.AdInterval = 90000;
        somaAdViewer.NewAdAvailable += somaAdViewer_NewAdAvailable;
        somaAdViewer.Format = SomaAd.FormatRequested.img;
        somaAdViewer.FormatStrict = true;
        startAds();
```

but when test on emulator, it always show smaato test banner.
it not show banner ads.
does i miss something?
i need to add Paypal account to get banner ads from Smaato?

Answer (score 2):

Did you solve your problem?
If you just set

```
AdSpaceId = 0;
PublisherId = 0;
```

then there should appear a test-add.
Does this work for you?
If yes we could go on.